# Error when using forward slash inside a string

Tags: lua, scrapy-splash, splash-js-render

I'm getting an error when I try to use forward slashes inside a string:

```
splash:evaljs('document.querySelector("a[href=/some/link/path/]")')
```

If I take the splashes out it's ok, do I need to escape the forward slashes?

**EDIT**

I'm using it with evaljs in the DOM context the error is: "SyntaxError: Dom exception 12"

Comment: Can you include the exact error message?

Comment: @Nifim Please see my edit

Comment: Don't you need to enclose the path in quotes? In this case, you need to escape the inner quotes.

Comment: Surely you don't need to escape the inner quotes when the string uses single instead of double quotes as a string declaration? Isn't everything inside the single quotes treated as raw?

Comment: I've tried using extra quotes and escaping like so: 'document.querySelector("a[href=\"/en-gb/betting/football/\"]")' but no luck